# Sent value from an action to another action

Tags: asp.net-core

How to pass the parameter from the first method to the second?
I want to use `id` in `public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReport`.

```cs
public IActionResult CreateReport(int id)
{       
  return View();
}

// POST: MemeReports/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReport([Bind("Id_report,Id_user,Id_meme,Description")] MemeReports memeReports)
{
  memeReports.id_meme=id //i want do this
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     db.Add(memeReports);
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
     return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
  }
  return View(memeReports);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass it in your post method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReport(int id, [Bind("Id_report,Id_user,Id_meme,Description")] MemeReports memeReports)
    {
        memeReports.id_meme=id //i want do this
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Add(memeReports);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(memeReports);
    }
```

Your first method gets called if the site yourdomain/createreport/1 (or yourdomain/createreport?id=1) is called and shows the createReport View.

If you submit a post from that page you will post the id, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TempData which stores data until it's read :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#tempdata

In `ConfigureServices` function :

```
services.Configure<CookieTempDataProviderOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

services.AddSession();
```

In `Configure` function :

```
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseSession();
```

Then in `CreateReport` function :

```
public IActionResult CreateReport(int id)
{
    TempData["id"] = 1;

    return View();
}
```

You can read this value in post function :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateReport([Bind("Id_report,Id_user,Id_meme,Description")] MemeReports memeReports)
{
    var value = TempData != null ? (TempData["id"]?.ToString() ?? "No TempData Value") : "No TempData";
    memeReports.id_meme= value；
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Add(memeReports);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(memeReports);
}
```

TempData should work after the user **accepts the cookie policy** on the site.